# About Airbnb video jumbotron for iPad

Tags: javascript, css, html, frontend, user-agent

When visiting [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com.au/) from PC/MAC browsers, the homepage jumbotron will use HTML5 video as background even you resize browser to a quite small size (meaning it's not just media query). But when you use a tablet like iPad, the jumbotron will use image carousel instead.

Is it something like user agent detection? Anyone knows what's the trick?

Comment: Why would 'resize browser to a quite small size' mean it's not just media query?

Comment: Here's a media query just to prove @Jason's comment: `@media (max-width: 767px)
.intro-area {
  padding: 0;
}`
In any case though, this can be done with client's browser detection of course.

Comment: @Jason Sperske Actually I just want to ask how Airbnb detect client's browser in this case. Could you please show me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check the http://www.useragentstring.com/.

If you open Chrome dev tools and enable emulation by clicking the phone icon. You can emulate how mobile devices will render the web page.
[image]

Although some consider browser sniffing [to be bad practice](https://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/)